# Android Tabbar bouncing on getSupportActionBar hide

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-actionbar, tabwidget

I have an Android app whose structure is:

- A tabbar (bottom of the screen).
- Each tab has a toolbar (just below the Action bar).

One of the Fragments has a GridView and I want to hide the ActionBar when the user scroll the grid. This is working ok, but during the hide antimation the Tabbar instead of stay fixed at the bottom of the screen, it makes some kind of bounce.

These are the XML.

- The tabbar activity.

  ```
  < android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

  < RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   < FrameLayout
  android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

  < TabWidget
  android:id="@android:id/tabs"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
  android:paddingTop="5dp"
  android:background="@color/white"/>

  < /RelativeLayout>

  < /android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
  ```
- Each tab fragment XML:

  ```
  < android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" / >
  ```
- Each fragment has its own XML, but the one that I want to ask for is this. It's just a fragment with a GridView.

  ```
     < FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <GridView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_grid_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp" />

   < /FrameLayout>
  ```

Inside this fragment I added a OnScrollListener to this GridView:

```
    gridView = (GridView)fragment.findViewById(R.id.fragment_grid_id);
    gridAdapter = new MyGridAdapter(getActivity(), myItems);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    gridView.setOnScrollListener(this);
```

And the listener methods are these:

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(final AbsListView view, final int scrollState) {
}

@Override
public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem, final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
    int currentFirstVisPos = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    if(currentFirstVisPos > scrollPrevItem) {
        ((ActionBarActivity)myActivity).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
    else if(currentFirstVisPos < scrollPrevItem) {
        ((ActionBarActivity)myActivity).getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
    scrollPrevItem = currentFirstVisPos;
}
```

As I told, when the user scrolls down the actionbar hides but the tabbar makes some kind of bounce that is awfull.

Anyone could tell me how to fix the tabbar to the bottom during the hide animation?

Thank you very much!